# Using Bitlocker and hidden volume feature of VeraCrypt together

Tags: encryption, bitlocker, veracrypt

I'm currently using Bitlocker encrypted external hard drive. The drive is entire-encrypted and single partition.

After dividing the drive into partition A and B, I'm planning to make a hidden volume using VeraCrypt on partition B.

So partition B will be encrypted with VeraCrypt and the hidden volume will be created within it in the process, while maintaining Bitlocker entire drive encryption.

I wonder if the Bitlocker entire drive encryption and hidden volume feature of VC will work properly. Can this make some problems or collisions arise due to any inference of two encryption programs?

Comment: An encryption algorithm doesn't care about the data it is being fed. All it sees are bytes that go in and bytes that go out. It doesn't care if these bytes are the result of another encryption algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will work.

You can also use VC/TC containers created on a VC/TC-encrypted partition/drive with no problem whatsoever.